# Visual Studio Code - problem about running code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Im new and I started to learn python some time ago but today I have small problem about running code in Visual Studio Code.
When i try to run code then i got:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlDyM.png)

Can you explane me why i got this? And how can I fix it?

I tried nothing and i just expect fast answer

Comment: SO participants very rarely answer questions that show no effort on the questioners part to solve it.  Come back with more specific errors you run into.  And don't link to images to explain your problem.

Comment: What is your question? What results do you hope to get?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are not running the code but debugging the code. What you show in the picture is just some powershell commands to debug the code.

Because vscode uses the system's built-in terminal (power shell or cmd), the execution command is displayed when you run or debug the code. The advantage of this is that the code can be run without hassle anywhere.

[image]

If you don't want the terminal to display these commands, you can use the [**Code Runner**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) to output the results in the **OUTPUT** panel.

[image]